# SQL Inner joining a select statement of a calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm working on a project where I have to get information about a physical exercise someone has taken. I get the information with the following query.

```
SELECT haas2.trainings.id,
       haas2.trainings.timestamp,
       haas2.training_types.NAME,
       haas2.training_types.description,
       haas2.training_types.intensity,
       haas2.training_types.length
FROM   haas2.trainings
       INNER JOIN haas2.training_types
               ON haas2.trainings.typeid = haas2.training_types.id
WHERE  guid = (SELECT guid
               FROM   haas2.users
               WHERE  login = 'mphdijck')
```

It takes the info from the table that holds all trainings and which user took them and then gets the extra info from the table holding the info about that specific training type.

It returns like this:

[image: Table return]

Now here comes the problem, I want to get the actual time the training took by calculating the time difference between the first sensor value and the last sensor value so that I know how long the training took.

I have the following statement for that:

```
SELECT 
       Max(Unix_timestamp(timestamp)) - Min(Unix_timestamp(timestamp)) AS output,
       haas2.trainingdata.training_id
FROM   haas2.trainingdata
WHERE  training_id = 1
```

This returns like this:

[image: Table return 2]

My problem would be solved if the second query would return the time for every training because then i could INNER JOIN it on the first query. But as it is right now it can only return the training from the training_id declared in the WHERE clause.

I hope this makes sense. I've done my best to explain my problem as clear as I can. If any clarification is needed please do ask.

Update: Example of the trainingdata table

[image: Trainingdata table]

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Raspberryano exactly, that is what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Milan van Dijck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, I think you need: SELECT MAX( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) ) - MIN( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( timestamp ) ) AS output, HAAS2.trainingdata.training_id FROM HAAS2.trainingdata GROUP BY training_id.